# How to simulate mouse click with the WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

Using the `WebBrowser` control I am able to call an event when the mouse button is manually clicked, but I want the program to do the click itself, not do something when I manually perform the click.

For example, if I provide the ID of a control on the page I want the program to click it.

Here's what I have so far:

```
HtmlElement button = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("lButtonSearch");
button.Click += new HtmlElementEventHandler(GotoSearchPage);
```

Comment: Is this to build a web app/site test harness by any chance? :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quite easily, simply use:

```
button.InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: @Nick - Sure, no problem. If you're doing any kind of (medium->high scale) Automation, I do recommend looking at WatiN (http://watin.sourceforge.net). Great project.

Comment: I looked at WatiN shortly after and have been using it ever since for many projects, thanks.