# Invoke click action for javascript confirmation box in C# browser

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control, invoke, dom

I wrote a browser in C# and it navigates custom pages, invokes specified buttons by using navigated "HtmlDocument". However, one of the buttons displays a confirmation box written in JS.

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure ?');"
```

This is not my call and how can I click on "OK" for this confirmation by using WebBrowser elements? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simulate mouse click with the WebBrowser control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150610/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-with-the-webbrowser-control)

Comment: Sorry, but I am talking about JS confirmation that also terminates debug and other functions. Its button does not exist in HtmlDocument of the page. So, it is neither same nor similar.

Comment: so you want to click on yes button after confirms appear?

Comment: as a work-around I avoided the confirmation message by using this line: document.Body.InnerHtml = document.Body.InnerHtml.Replace("onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure ?');\"", "");

Comment: @JoshuaJeanThree that is probably what you are going to have to do. That confirm message won't go away any other way, unless you have something looking at the process (on the browser) and close it.