# How to send mouse events to a minimized form in c#?

Tags: c#, background, mouse

I try to write a simple tester tool, it testing web site (win form, using WebBrowser control).
I need to send mouse click and keystrokes to the site.
It works when the form is on top, but i would like to run the tester in the background. **How can i send mouse click, keystrokes to a minimized/background form?**
Current mouse event code:

```
[DllImport( "user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall )]
public static extern void mouse_event( uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo );

[Flags]
public enum MouseEventFlags
{
    LEFTDOWN = 0x00000002,
    LEFTUP = 0x00000004,
    MIDDLEDOWN = 0x00000020,
    MIDDLEUP = 0x00000040,
    MOVE = 0x00000001,
    ABSOLUTE = 0x00008000,
    RIGHTDOWN = 0x00000008,
    RIGHTUP = 0x00000010
}

void mouseEvent( uint flag, Point p )
{
    p = caller.PointToScreen( p );

    Cursor.Position = p;
    mouse_event( flag, (uint) 0, (uint) 0, (uint) 0, (UIntPtr) 0 );
}
public void sendMouseClick( Point p )
{
    uint flag = (uint) MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN + (uint) MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP;

    mouseEvent( flag, p );
}
```

*-- Edited:*

I tried the SendMessage but didn't works :(
Currently i try to use a simple from with 2 buttons, no web browser, just normal windows.Form and buttons. i try to click button1 from code when i push the button2. :)

```
        // On the form, when i press the button 2 then minimize, wait, and try to press the button1
    private void button2_Click( object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this.RaiseMouseEvent();
        MouseHelper mh = new MouseHelper(this.Text);
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        Thread.Sleep( 2000 );
        this.Refresh();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        mh.SendMouseClick( 25,25 );
    }

    private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        throw new Exception( "BUTTON 1 CLICKED" );
    }

    // In the MouseHelper I call the left click
    public void SendMouseClick( int p_x, int p_y )
    {
        Int32 l_parm1 = (p_y << 16) | (p_x & 0xffff);
        SendMessage( windowPtr, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, l_parm1 );
        SendMessage( windowPtr, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, l_parm1 );
    }

    public MouseHelper( String windowTitle )
    {
        windowPtr = FindWindowByCaption( IntPtr.Zero, windowTitle );
    }

    // defintions
    public const uint WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    public const uint WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

    [DllImport( "user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall )]
    public static extern int SendMessage(
        IntPtr hWnd,
        uint Msg,
        Int32 wParam,
        Int32 lParam
    );
```

What I did wrong?

It doesn't work even the window is not minimezed:( The 1st solution works when window is active, but the 2nd not :(
I tried with 25,25 and 147,47 (result of PoinToScreen of 25,25)

Answer (score 0):

Probably SendMessage would work.
See [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [System Defined Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system_defined) (more specifically [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Something like:

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, (123<<16)|(456));
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, (123<<16)|(456));
```

Comment: thx, i tried, but not good :( see above in the question after "-- Edited" mark

Comment: Okay, so one reason could be the implementation of the Webbrowser control. You might also consider accessing the methods of the WebBrowser control (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150610/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-with-the-webbrowser-control)) and use Javascript for your testing.

Comment: sorry, the button1 is a standard winforms button, is not in the WebBrowser. I try to build from step by step :) the button1 is a normal System.Windows.Forms.Button on a panel on the form, not in the  browser control.

Comment: Please edit your Question to match the Requirements specified here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry, i modified the question header